# Why pagination is not applied to grid when using common data source

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I referred Kendo articles and did goggling  ,But I couldn't found any solution.
step 1:

Is it possible that when we are using common data source and  binding the whole data to chart and grid with pagination this is to happen when the page is loading.

step 2:

later on based on the filter condition applied on grid the data in chart should change.

Any help or suggest me whether it is possible or not..

```
var common = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type     : "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                OrderDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    }

});
common.read();

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: common,
     pageSize : 10,
    pageable  : {

        refresh  : true,
        pageSizes: [10, 20]
    },
    filterable:true,
    columns   : [
        {
            field     : "OrderID",
            filterable: false
        },
        "Freight",
        {
            field : "OrderDate",
            title : "Order Date",
            width : 100,
            format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            field: "ShipName",
            title: "Ship Name",
            width: 200,
            filterable: true
        },
        {
            field: "ShipCity",
            title: "Ship City",
            filterable: true
        }
    ]

}).data("kendoGrid");
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource  : common,
    autoBind    : false,
    categoryAxis: {
        field: "OrderID"
    },
    legend      : {
        position: "right", visible: true
    },

    seriesDefaults: { type: "area" },
    series        : [
        { field: "OrderDate", name: "OrderDate" },
        { field: "Freight", name: "Freight" },
        { field: "ShipVia", name: "ShipVia" }
    ],
    valueAxis     : [
        {
            name   : "OrderID",
            max    : 5.0,
            min    : 0,
            labels : {
                format: "{0}"
            },
            tooltip: { visible: true }
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is fiddle up to now I have tested with : http://jsfiddle.net/D3rSk/189/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid doesn't have a pageSize option. You need to set the page size in the data source configuration:

```
var common = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    pageSize : 10,  
    type     : "odata",
    transport: {
        read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
    },
    schema   : {
        model: {
            fields: {
                OrderDate: { type: "date" }
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Here is the updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3rSk/192/

Comment: But  chart data is also reflecting with the same.I want the grid with pagination in shared datasource when page is loading.And chart with entire data.After that based on my pagesize selection only graph should update.

Comment: This can't happen with a shared data source because it is shared. If you page the data source - all widgets bound to it will get only one page of data.

Comment: Is there any alternative because I need to show up the chart with all the data.later all the operations should be done

Comment: The alternative is to have two data sources.

Comment: One doubt while page is loading is it possible to keep auto bind false to grid .